# How to hide parent element with css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide the parent element of the element 'child'. It will be better. Do anyone know to do this with pure css. If there is no way to do so.. JavaScript is also Ok for me

**Code**

```
<h2>
  <span id="child">
  Lorem Ipsum
  </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with pure CSS. CSS **by design** (for reasons I won't get into) does not have a "parent-of" or "ancestor-of" selector.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('#child').parentNode`

Comment: So do you mean, make the parent disappear, but not the child? As far as I am aware, if you get hide the parent, the child will disappear, so if that's what you mean, we will need to find some way around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for( const el of document.querySelectorAll( '.child' ) ) {
        const ancestorH2 = el.closest( 'h2' );
        if( ancestorH2 ) ancestorH2.style.display = 'none';
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this in js?

```
  var x = document.getElementById("child").parentElement;
  x.style.display = 'none';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49otfmgw/